# DecisionTreeRegressor on GridSearchCV Key error mse/squared_root

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to make a tuning in a DecisionTreeRegressor with GridSearchCV but each time I change de criterion it raises a key error for that specific criterion. This is my first try:

```
   params = {
       "criterion":('squared_root', 'absolute_error', 'poisson'), 
       "splitter":("best", "random"), 
       "max_depth":(list(range(1, 20))), 
       "min_samples_split":[2, 3, 4], 
       "min_samples_leaf":list(range(1, 20)), 
   }
   
   
   tree_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=42)
   tree_reg = GridSearchCV(tree_reg, params, scoring="accuracy", n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, cv=3)
   tree_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
   best_params = tree_reg.best_params_
   print(f"Best paramters: {best_params}")
```

and it raised KeyError squared_root.

Then I changed it to mse in the params grid  and it raised the KeyError mse. I've also tried it with less params just to test the changes and there it had no problem:

```
   params = {
       "criterion":('mse', 'absolute_error')
   }
   
   
   tree_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=42)
   tree_reg = GridSearchCV(tree_reg, params, scoring="accuracy", n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, cv=3)
   tree_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Also my sklearn version is 0.24.2

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for your module version, the criterions for DecisionTreeRegressor could be one of `“mse”, “friedman_mse”, “mae”, “poisson”`
https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor

This at least explains `KeyError squared_root`.

Comment: That's why I tried changing it but the same problem rose, but with mse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an outdated sklearn version. Try upgrading it to '1.2.2' (current stable version) via the following:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

You might still get the key error since you are passing the 'criterion' parameters as tuple `()`. Replace your `params` with the following:

```
params = {
    'criterion': {'mse', 'mae', 'poisson'},
    'splitter': {'best', 'random'},
    'max_depth': list(range(1, 20)),
    'min_samples_split': [2, 3, 4],
    'min_samples_leaf': list(range(1, 20)),
}

tree_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 42)
tree_reg = GridSearchCV(tree_reg, params, verbose = 1, cv = 3)
```

Also, I noticed you are using `scoring = 'accuracy'` in the Grid-search algorithm. I assume you are performing regression task here. Accuracy is an evaluation metric generally used for classification problems not regression.